# Azure Subscription - Twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: azure

So we have twitter sentiment analysis been set up using Power Automate+ Power BI + Twitter dev API. Everything was working fine till this month start. However suddenly we started getting the below error Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource" . On futher investigation found out that my Azure subcription is disabled.(free account). However the free account was set up only 2 months ago.

Questions  -

1. How did the Subcription got disabled within 2 months.
2. I read few articles is it true the free azure benfits can be availed for the subcriptions which are in US West Central?
3. If #2 is true ,  there a way wherein we can change the location of the subcription to US west Central.
4. What would be the solution for this issue?

Comment: I believe these questions would be better addressed by Azure customer support.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/

Answer (score 0):

Your free subsctiption has quotas and probably you ran out of credits. You just need to switch to pay as you go subscription mode (with your credit card) and the solution should work again. For more information about the quotas, please read the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits